# Deadlock caused by method requiring threads

Tags: java, multithreading, download

I'm currently having trouble figuring out the proper way to do this.

I have a ExecutorService with a fixed thread pool of 64. I'm requesting to download a kind of Book (one at a time). To download a book I need to: download the book info, download page info and then download a part of the book. When I request to download a book I get every page info and in the same method I download those little parts of the book. The problem is downloading those little parts of books is also done asynchronously (requiring another thread) but at the time all of 64 threads are occupied by the page-downloading threads. I've came up with either adding another ExecutorService or lifting the thread pool to some bigger number like 256. But that just don't feels quite right. Do I have any other options?

Summary of steps and location of the problem:

1. download book info
2. download page:

   - page info
   - page part by part -- Deadlock - out of threads.

     ```
     @Override
     public Book getBook(int bookId) {
         Book book = books.get(bookId);
         if (book == null) {
             HttpURLConnection conn = factory.getBook(bookId);
             String s = read(conn);
             book = interpret.readBook(s);

             books.put(book.getId(), book);
         }

         return book;
     }

     @Override
     public Page getPage(int bookId, int pageNum) {
         String s = read(factory.getPage(bookId, pageNum));
         List<Integer> eIds = interpret.readExercises(s);
         List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>(eIds.size());
         CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(eIds.size());

         System.out.println("D: Requesting to dl page " + bookId + '>' + pageNum);
         for (int eId : eIds) {
             System.out.println("eId" + eId);
             service.submit(() -> {
                 try {
                     // The code here does not execute to the lack of free threads
                     System.out.println("D: Requesting to dl exer " + eId);
                     String sE = read(factory.getExercise(bookId, eId));
                     Exercise exercise = interpret.readExercise(sE);
                     exercises.add(exercise);
                     latch.countDown();
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             });
         }

         try {
             latch.await();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return new Page(pageNum, exercises);
     }

     @Override
     public WholeBook getWholeBook(int bookId) {
         Book book = getBook(bookId);
         List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>(book.getPages().size());
         CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(book.getPages().size());
         System.out.println("D: Requesting to dl book " + bookId);
         for (int pageNum : book.getPages()) {
             service.submit(() -> {
                 try {
                     Page page = getPage(bookId, pageNum);
                     System.out.println("Got page: " + page);
                     pages.add(page);
                     latch.countDown();
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             });
         }

         try {
             System.out.println("Waiting for book " + bookId);
             latch.await();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return null; // Better to return null rather than corrupted data
         }

         return new WholeBook(book, pages);
     }
     ```

The end of the output is:

`D: Requesting to dl page 10753>67
eId235082
eId235092`
After that it stops (is technically running but not doing anything)

When I interrupt the thread (using debugger) stack trace points to #getPage and to be more exact to `latch.await()`.

Comment: Needs code, and I'd prefer something self-contained that doesn't need to actually access the network.  That said, I don't see why this should 'deadlock' or starve.  Once you finish with a task, the thread should be available for a new task.

Comment: @Kayaman added code

Comment: @markspace but the task requires another thread to actually complete

Comment: This is probably not the issue, but I'd prefer to see you actually throw exceptions rather than catch them and just print a stack trace.  The potential for error exists if you don't tell higher level code that an error occurred.

Comment: @markspace actually I did it mainly for debugging thanks for your proposition.When the code is running there aren't actually any exceptions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're executing two different kinds of tasks, and the second one is a subtask of the first one, you end up with the executor being full of the first tasks, which can't finish since their subtasks can't execute. While this is not a classic example of a deadlock, I'd say it qualifies.

The way I would handle this is by removing the use of the executor in `getPage()`. If for some reason (although I fail to see any valid reason) you want/need to keep the `getPage()` using multiple threads, you'll have to provide a separate `Executor` for it to use, so the subtasks will always have a chance to finish.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help

Comment: Isn't this also a classic case for `ForkJoinTask`?

Comment: @biziclop Yea, that would be a lot cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

Technically not a dead-lock you are reporting. You're running out of threads.

Looks like your threads are doing a lot of I/O work (which is fine), but if you are not closing those connections, it's possible that the tasks are not completing and the ThreadPool is unable to re-allocate the threads for other tasks.

UPDATE: I see, you have threads that depend upon each other. In general this is a bad idea. What you probably want to do is create a processing pipeline.  Do one part, place the result into a queue. Have another executor service for reading off of the queue to complete the request.

Comment: I know I'm running out of threads and I am closing connections but to complete the task it requires another thread to complete. That's the main problem - how to handle it